# Java: Do Thread pools execute tasks simultaneously or sequentially?

Tags: java

My understanding of thread pool is that that when you pass a thread pool a method it picks a thread from its active pool and sends the method off to be executed. My understanding of a thread is that if you put some code in it, it will run through the code without stopping until it is told to sleep or stop.

My question:

When you pass several methods (of roughly equal length to execute) to a thread pool one after another does the thread pool manage sharing between the different threads being executed so that the tasks finish almost simultaneously or does it execute them one after another - for example, task 1 goes into thread 1, thread 1 starts executing it and thread 2 with task 2 in it hasn't had a chance to run until task task 1 has finished because thread 1 was running through the code it has been given without any explicit messages to sleep - so then thread 2 will execute and the tasks will essentially finish one after another.

**Basically, do I have to explicitly make sure the code I give to a thread pool has a breaks in it for the threads to run simultaneously? Or do I get this for free when using a thread pool manager?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1.** The **number of Thread you specify in the pool works simultaneously**, thats what threads are for, to simultaneously do the work. Its a **Parallel Run**

**2.** For example FixedThreadPool, will have certain nos of threads, when you give them a certain nos of tasks to be performed,  all runs simultaneously to do it, if the number of work is less than the threads in the pool, then only those many thread which are needed to perform the task will run simultaneously.

**3.** In case of CachedThreadPool, the number of threads in the pool run simultaneously to complete the work, if there is a need of more thread,  CachedThreadPool will create new ones or till then it reuses it.

Comment: This is not what the OP is looking for. He already knows this, i assume. What he needs to know is how the JVM schedules threads.

Comment: He wanted to know whether the threads will run in parallel or not..and i have answer it, in my 1st point. The other 2 points are examples....

Comment: You should read the question correctly... he doesnt need the info about the Thread Scheduler, but the Paralle, running of the thread from the pools.

Comment: So if I pass the Thread Pool three endless tasks with While(true) loops and no sleep commands and then put another While(true) statement in my Main thread, say they are all just printing a different message. Will they all execute and show up all their different messages without me interfering? Or does the program get stuck on the first loop? (Sorry about the hypothetical question, I'm trying to work out if what I think I know about threads is what is actually happening)

Comment: Thought Thread from the pool will run simultaneously, but as you have not used any sleep(), it will be the Thread-Scheduler who will be in full command of the threads, and will determine that Which thread will be in runnable state, for How long, and Where will the thread go once it is kicked off of the runnable state

Comment: @JohnSmith It depends on how the thread pool is configured. If you submit 3 jobs to the thread pool, and it is only configured with a single thread, the first job will hog the thread, and the other tasks will wait forever. If it's configured with 3 or more threads, they will all execute simultaneously. See the documentation in java.util.concurrent.Executors.

Comment: @ wolfcastle ok! Thanks. That makes my life much much easier.

Answer (score 3):

OP seems thinking in the way of old cooperative multitasking, in the way that a thread should sleep/yield in order to give up the CPU to another thread/process to run.

However, it is not the case in Java (or at least, for most common JVM implementations).  Multi-tasking is preemptive in Java.  That means, when Thread 1 is running, even you don't do any yield/sleep explicitly, Thread 2 will be able to run at the same time (by time slicing/running in another CPU core etc).

Answer (score 1):

With more than one thread, it will run the tasks in parallel. The pool uses all available threads (available = configured for the pool).

Answer (score 1):

There is no guarantee concerning the run order, it depends on a lot of stuff; but if the tasks are long enough you can assume that the tasks will be run simultaneously.